# total number of rows should be equal to max id in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

this is the table

```
id

1
2
10
15
19
```

is it possible to get an output like this

```
row id
1   1
2   2
3   null
4   null
5   null
6   null
7   null
8   null
9   null
10  10
11  null 
12  null
13  null
14  null
15  15
16  null
17  null
18  null  
19  19
```

Answer (score 0):

A numbers table can make your query very easy. A table that has numbers in sequence. You just need a LEFT JOIN with table.
e.g.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(ID INT)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(1), (3),(10), (15) 

;WITH numbers AS
(
SELECT 1 AS N
UNION ALL
SELECT N + 1
FROM numbers 
WHERE N < 1000

)

SELECT *
FROM numbers A 
LEFT JOIN @T B
ON A.N = B.ID
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

In this example i have generated the numbers till 1000, you can avoid that by joining an existing table that an integer column with values in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   TOP (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Your_Table) num.n AS row,
   tbl.id AS id
FROM numbers num
   LEFT JOIN Your_Table tbl
      ON num.n = tbl.id
```